# BoF return address overwrite problem with \x0A and \x00

Tags: c, x86, buffer-overflow, gets

I have code in C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int cookie;
    char buf[16];
    printf("&buf: %p, &cookie: %p\n", buf, &cookie);
    gets(buf);
    if (cookie == 0x000D0A00)
        printf("You win!\n");
}
```

`file: ELF-32bit-i386` BoF cannot be exploited by overwriting the cookie variable (due to the **0x000D0A00** that contains the  **\x0A** character). So I did overwrite the return address (**$eip**) but it went wrong. Here is the ASM code I compiled using GDB and the python code I use to exploit.

[image: ASM code for main funcion]

```py
import struct

cookie = 'A'*4
buf = 'B'*16
ebp = 'C'*4
eip = struct.pack("I", 0x00001209)
print cookie+buf+ebp+eip
```

**How to rewrite the EIP to 0x00001209 (i.e. ignore the conditional branch and rewrite the return address that is the address of the printf function)?**

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Nothing of this makes any sense.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. But how to exploit this program?

Comment: copy the disassembly text and paste here, not in an image

Comment: @phuclv dài quá em không coppy được @@. cái bài này có cả hướng dẫn, mà em làm thấy cứ sai sai

Answer (score 2):

The test is unlikely to succeed on windows systems because it requires for the user to enter a null byte before the CRLF sequence. You should instead write:

```
  if (cookie == 0x0A0D)
```

If the compiler allocates `cookie` after `buf` in the stack, which can be verified with the `printf` call, entering a 16 byte string and hit enter, the 16 bytes will go into `buf` and the next 2 bytes will go into the 2 low bytes of `cookie`. These bytes are `0x0D` and `0x0A`, the codes for CR and LF, the line terminator used by legacy systems.

Note however that `cookie` should be initialized to `0` so the high byte of `cookie` is `0` and the program must be compile with optimisations disabled too.